# How to read data from a file that is constantly being appended using another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I've got an problem "Create 2 threads,one will write data to a file(From a string defined in program) and other will read data from same file and display it on console". Here is my implementation,but it gets stuck in a infinite loop

```
import java.io.* 
class ReaderWriter {
 int ch;
 FileInputStream fin;
 FileOutputStream fout;
 boolean rdrblocked = false;
 static volatile boolean running;
 static volatile boolean eof = false;
 String s = "This will end up in a file in the same order as it appears here or else we can conclude that there is some discrepancy related to some race condition stuff";
 byte b[] = s.getBytes();
 int length = b.length;

 void writer() throws Exception {
  fout = new FileOutputStream("Demo.txt");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   fout.write(b[i]);
   if (rdrblocked) {
    synchronized(this) {
     rdrblocked = false;
     notify();
    }
   }
  }
  eof = true;
  while (running) {
   synchronized(this) {
    rdrblocked = false;
    notify();
   }
  }
  fin.close();

 }

 void reader() throws Exception {
  running = true;
  fin = new FileInputStream("Demo.txt");
  if (fin.available() > 0) {
   while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char) ch);
    while (fin.available() == 0 && !eof) {
     synchronized(this) {
      rdrblocked = true;
      wait();
     }
    }
   }
  }
  running = false;
  fin.close();
 }
}

class Writercall implements Runnable {
 Thread t;
 ReaderWriter obj;
 Writercall(ReaderWriter obj) {
  this.obj = obj;
  t = new Thread(this, "Reader");
  t.start();
 }
 public void run() {
  try {
   obj.writer();
  } catch (Exception e) {}
 }
}

class Readercall implements Runnable {
 Thread t;
 ReaderWriter obj;
 Readercall(ReaderWriter obj) {
  this.obj = obj;
  t = new Thread(this, "Writer");
  t.start();
 }
 public void run() {
  try {
   obj.reader();
  } catch (Exception e) {}
 }
}

class RWDemo {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  ReaderWriter obj1 = new ReaderWriter();
  Readercall r = new Readercall(obj1);
  Writercall w = new Writercall(obj1);
  try {
   r.t.join();
   w.t.join();
  } catch (Exception e) {}
 }
}
```

Any helps and better implementations are appreciated.
P.S: I have used volatile as well as isAAlive() but it does not work.The problem i believe is in the while loop of writer where the update of boolean variable running to false by reader is not getting reflected in reader.
P.P.S: Yes guys i know this is a inefficient way of achieving concurrency but i am just curious if this will work.
Edit: I have updated code as per suggestions of muradm.Any improvements to code are still welcomed.(Updated code is linked above)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback coder,but i am looking to achieve a readwrite concurrency insttead of a read and a write concurrency  as i believe that there will be no race conditions in the problem i am looking to solve(If you feel there are some which i have left, please point it out)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to open same file instantly. Just to give you idea:

```
// omitted
void reader() throws Exception {
    // reader waits before writer notify
    // writer notifies reader to wake up
    synchronized (this) {
        rdrblocked = true;
        wait();
    }
    while (!new File("Demo.txt").exists() && running) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
    fin = new FileInputStream("Demo.txt");
    if (fin.available() > 0) {
        while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) ch);
        }
    }
    // omitted
```

I.e. since file does not exists in the beginning, then both reader and writer may acquire different handles from OS. Making reader to check if file exists and waiting for its existence, will do the trick, but still...

However, it does not seems to be a good solution. Your purpose is unclear:

- are you going to continuously read and write to the file, or is it one time operation? If continuously, then you have to keep `EOF` in mind, once reader reaches it, your handle should be invalid, although writer could continue writing to the file after reader's `EOF` event.
- why do you do such thing in the scope of single process?

If there is real task behind it, you will need to look for more complex solution to achieve reliable reading/writing from single file. Like `RandomAccessFile` or else.

Also, if you are working out `wait()` and `notify()`, then `wait()` should occur before `notify()`, other wise, if you are `wait()` after data read from file, then writer actually `notified()` before even reader started to `wait()`. I.e. waiter will miss the notifies, happened before `wait()` call.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback muradm.Now regarding your concerns, 1)The program indeed is acquiring same file handles each time during execution else the reader would not be able to read the text and display it on console.(However this is very valid and i will add it as it makes things more reliable) 2)No, this is a one time process, i.e after the string defined in my program exhausts, the program will be successfully terminated. 3)I need this in the scope of a single process because the university's assignment...so yes,i am on training wheels on this java cycle

Comment: btw yes,i have already considered and taken care eof perspective in the reader code :)

Comment: not so easy, with `EOF`, there are so many unpredictable conditions could happen. Imagine case, where, writer created file, but not written anything yet, reader opened and reached `EOF`, before writer written somethings. unpredictable... Also have a look at edit with `wait/notify`

Comment: yes,i will add on this one..any more breakpoints you notice in code?Do let me know

Comment: Hi muradm,i have included the changes you mentioned and the program seems to  work fine and as expected.Thank you.Any additions to improve efficiency or as said above any part of code that may break in some peculiar situations are welcomed :)